Flutter Riverpod using StreamProvider to retrieve data from Firestore
I am kinda new to flutter i am having trouble understanding streamproviders if i want to recieve a iterable of data from  firestore this works but i saw a lot of people creating a stream inside the stream provider and they sub to the firestore collection stream that firebase provide they also use .listen instead of .map any information would be helpful, also if both are correct is there a reason to use one over the other
final allCreatorsProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Iterable<Creator>>(
  (ref) {
    final stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(creatorsCollection)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshots) => snapshots.docs
            .where(
              (doc) => !doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites,
            )
            .map(
              (doc) => Creator.fromSnapshot(doc),
            ));
    return stream;
  },
);

this is the code i saw
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:testingriverpod/state/constants/firebase_collection_name.dart';
import 'package:testingriverpod/state/constants/firebase_field_name.dart';
import 'package:testingriverpod/state/posts/models/post.dart';

final allPostsProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Iterable<Post>>(
  (ref) {
    final controller = StreamController<Iterable<Post>>();

    final sub = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(
          FirebaseCollectionName.posts,
        )
        .orderBy(
          FirebaseFieldName.createdAt,
          descending: true,
        )
        .snapshots()
        .listen(
      (snapshots) {
        final posts = snapshots.docs.map(
          (doc) => Post(
            json: doc.data(),
            postId: doc.id,
          ),
        );
        controller.sink.add(posts);
      },
    );

    ref.onDispose(() {
      sub.cancel();
      controller.close();
    });

    return controller.stream;
  },
);


It's totally normal to feel a bit confused when you're starting with Flutter and dealing with streams.
1. Using .map() (The Simple Way):
How It Works: You grab the stream from Firestore, and with .map(), you directly transform each piece of data into what you need, like a list of your custom Creator objects.
When to Use It: This is great when you just want to take the data and immediately make it usable in your app, without needing to do anything extra.
Why It’s Nice: It’s straightforward, clean, and you don’t have to manage anything yourself. Flutter does the heavy lifting.
final allCreatorsProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Iterable<Creator>>((ref) {
  final stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(creatorsCollection)
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshots) => snapshots.docs
          .where((doc) => !doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites)
          .map((doc) => Creator.fromSnapshot(doc)));
  return stream;
});

2. Using .listen() with a StreamController (The Hands-On Way):
How It Works: Here, you’re getting the stream, but instead of just transforming it, you’re manually listening to the data as it comes in.
This gives you the chance to do more things with each piece of data, like logging, additional processing, or anything else you might need.
When to Use It: Use this when you need to handle more complex scenarios, like multiple steps of processing, or if you need to react to each new piece of data in a special way.
Why It’s Nice: It gives you full control over what happens with your data. You can clean up resources when you’re done, or handle errors more gracefully.
dart
final allPostsProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Iterable<Post>>((ref) {
  final controller = StreamController<Iterable<Post>>();

  final sub = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshots) {
        final posts = snapshots.docs.map(
          (doc) => Post(
            json: doc.data(),
            postId: doc.id,
          ),
        );
        controller.sink.add(posts);
      });

  ref.onDispose(() {
    sub.cancel();
    controller.close();
  });

  return controller.stream;
});

3. So, Which Should You Choose?
If you just want to grab the data and get it into your app with as little fuss as possible, go with .map(). It’s simple, clean, and does exactly what you need with no extra work.
If you need more control, like handling errors, logging, or doing something special with each piece of data as it comes in, then .listen() with a StreamController gives you that power.
Both methods are totally valid—it just depends on how much control you need. I hope this clears things up!

thanks for the clarification, could you possibly give an example of an operation that could be done on each piece of data, could that be filtering, even though i can filter the collection before i use listen or map

actually i think i undestood it, correct me if im wrong but if .listen subscribes to the stream meaning any changes will be reflected instantly, while with .map it happens once you map them into an iterable then move on, but that opens up another question does that mean i can just use a futureprovider

To clarify:
.listen() subscribes to the stream and reacts immediately to any changes. Every time new data arrives, your listener will trigger, so it’s perfect for real-time, continuous updates or when you need to handle things like side effects (e.g., logging, notifications, etc.).
.map() transforms each piece of data as it comes through the stream, and is more about creating a pipeline for data to be processed in a functional way. The mapping happens each time a new snapshot is received, but you’re focusing on transforming data rather than reacting with side effects.

Use .listen() when you need to react to each new piece of data, especially if you need to handle side effects or complex logic.
Use .map() when you’re transforming data and don’t need to manually handle the subscription.
Choose FutureProvider for one-time data fetches and StreamProvider for real-time, continuous data streams.
